# Passing Arguments to custom action in MSM from MSI - Installshield

Tags: installshield

[Screenshot of custom action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih7Me.png)

edit: where should I mention the property as attribute? and how will the property created in MSM be exposed by the exe and how should it be set?

I am using an Basic MSI project to install a Merge Module, which internally invokes an .exe using custom action in differed mode. I would like to pass arguments to the custom action while invoking the exe. How can I pass arguments dynamically to the custom action?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly. You're only hope is that the custom action uses public properties as input parameters and pass the updated value for those properties when you call the MSM.

Comment: Hi Damon D, I have modified my question where I have attached a screenshot of my custom action, can you please point me on how to pass a property as argument to the custom action? and how it can be set while running the exe via command prompt?

Comment: What is the .exe file (is it a bootstrapped MSI installer)? What kind of project is it being called in: Basic MSI, MSM? Run the .exe file with `/?` on the command line to see how to pass in properties. If the exe is a bootstrapped MSI file, you cannot call it in the deferred execute sequence since you cannot have 2 MSI's in deferred execute at the same time.

Comment: The exe is an C# managed code application, Which is used to modify a file based on user input.

Comment: So then **you** are authoring the MSM and calling it from another MSI installer? Therefor, you need to get a property value from the main MSI down into the MSM and finally into your custom action?

Comment: Yes damon, thats right I need the property value to be passed from MSI to MSM and then the MSM will need to pass it to the custom action. I am using Installshield 2014.